# Why || operator is behaving like this?

Tags: javascript

Why `_value` is `foo` on second function call? It took me a while to find this bug.

```js
function doSomething(value) {
  console.log('should be:', value);
  const _value = value || Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : 'bar';
  console.log('actually is:', _value);
}

let values = ['foo', 'bar'];
const first = doSomething(values[0]);
const second = doSomething(values[1]);
```

Comment: Just figured it out myself, fix: `value || (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : 'bar')` *duh*

Comment: [MDN on operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand better I put a parenthes around the testing code:

```
(value || Math.random() > 0.5)
```

Since `value` is always defined (`non null`) the condition avaluates to true and assigns `'foo'` to '`_value`'

Hope this explains it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because the expression

```
const _value = value || Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

is evaluated as:

```
const _value =  (value || (Math.random() > 0.5)) ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

The **conditional operator has lower precedence than other operators in the expression.**

`value` is a non-empty string, so it evaluates to `true` in boolean context. Thus, the condition evaluates to `true`, and the final result is always `'foo'`.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
> 'bar' == true
false
```

So:

```
const _value = value || Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

`_value` will be randomly assigned the value `'foo'` or `'bar'`, because `value` is `'bar'` which evaluates to `false`, so the second half of the or-expression `||` is evaluated and assigned to `_value`.

Comment: But `if('bar') a = 1; else a = 3;` gives 1

Comment: @yesenin yeah, I don't know what I was thinking; I'm wrong.  Alex's answer is right, the issue is `||` has higher precedence than `?:` - duh.  Should I delete my answer?  Hm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const _value = value || (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : 'bar');
```

Because JS in your code check such

```
`if(value || Math.random() > 0.5){
_value = 'foo';
}else{
_value ='bar'
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The construct `const a = b || c` is common Javascript shorthand. It means:

If `b` is not *falsy* assign it to `a`. Otherwise assign `c` to `a`.

It can also be written `const a = b ? b : c;` or

```
const a;
if (b) a = b;
else a = c;
```

A value is *falsy* generally speaking if it is empty or has the value zero.